# Linux: Default prioirty of applications that run dynamically as tasks

Tags: linux

I'm a new user of linux and am confused about task priorities of applications that run dynamically at run time.

Here's the scenario:
1. I create an application called myApplication and install it in one of the bin folders (/usr/sbin)
2. This task is not run until 
         a. I start it specifically from shell or 
         b. I call it from a script based on some event.

1. The application executes and terminates.
2. How do I know its priority?

Q2. Will it take default priority and nice value? I see that my application's nice value is 0 which I assume is default.

Q3. How can I find the priority of all such applications that are installed in one of the bin folders but are called run time and terminate after their desired work is done?

I thoroughly searched the forum before posting this query and I apologize if it has already been answered.

Many many thanks in advance.
Keshav

Answer (score 1):

Programs don't generally have an associated nice value. The default is for spawned processes to inherit the parent's niceness, regardless of which program is being started. To change this you can use the `nice` or `renice` command-line utilities, or the `setpriority()` system call.

Comment: @Keshav: No problems (BTW, on SO, you thank people by up-voting and clicking the green tick. :-)